# Javascript prompt vs custom prompt. (chessboardjs promotion)

Tags: javascript, async-await, prompt, chess, chessboard.js

**backstory:** In chessboardjs you load the board with callback functions for specific events. Chess mechanic that gives me problem is the promotion. I need to hold my callback, prompt a user for a piece he wants to promote to, check if it is a valid move and return('snapback') or execute the move.

**Stupid solution:** If I prompt with classic

`promoPiece = prompt();`

everything works, but it looks kinda ugly.

**Failed solution:** But when I try to create a promise that attaches a callback to my overlay element, to get user click on specific piece I fail(i need to make function async to use promises). I try to get the piece as

```
async function onDrop(args)
{
  ..code..
  promoPiece = await promoPrompt();
  ..code..
  if(invalid())
  {return 'snapback'}
}
```

and the promotion mechanic works, but the return snapback statement does not work because now the promise is returned instead of a string and it is not accepted with the chessboardjs...(I assumed, I did not dig into source)

**Question:** 1)How does prompt differ from my solution? 2)How does it work? 3)How can i create a custom  promotion handler for a synchronous callback? 4)Can i use `promoPrompt.then(myResolve)` syntax without making `onDrop()` async?

Comment: Question #1: The difference is that `prompt` is synchronous, while `await promoPrompt()` is asynchronous.

Comment: As for question #4, the answer is yes, but it won't work as you intend. You cannot return a value to the calling context from within a promise callback.

Comment: You'll likely need to separate the two operations.  If this chessboard API supports doing so.  The callback from the chessboard system should just display the (asynchronous) prompt.  Then the operation invoked by that prompt should send some command to the chessboard API to make whatever updates are necessary.

Comment: As crazy as it may sound, I think your best option is to create a PR for chessboardjs to be able to accept an async onDrop function that awaits the result. It's hard telling what side effects that will have, but that's the nature of changing a library

Answer (score 0):

1. It is synchronous
2. Natively (i.e. the code is part of the browser and exposed as an API via the `prompt` function)
3. You can't (unless it is just a wrapper around `prompt` but then you get the native look and feel that you dislike)
4. Well, yes, but the value will won't be available until *that future* so you can't return it to the calling function

If you want a custom UI here, then the calling function needs to be able to handle it asynchronously.